# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type IEnumerable in MVC project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-3.5

This markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
         Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<FOO>>" %>
```

produces the error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IEnumerable' because 'IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I can get rid of the error by adding this markup:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

This strikes me as a very bad thing. I am working in VS2010 and started this project as an MVC project using .NET 4.0. I had to downgrade because .NET 4.0 isn't installed yet on our network. I suspect the downgrade caused the problem but I am at a loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: maybe you have not imported namespace which Foo class is declared. please import FOO class namespace. and add you code if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register the namespace for all views in your Web.config. Something like this should work:

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>       
        <addnamespace="System.Linq" />
      </namespaces>
</pages>
```